# Transform ServletInputStream to String

Tags: servlets, inputstream

I am trying to get the body of a HttpServletRequest in a String. What's the best elegant way to do so?

Comment: Use `request.getInputStream()` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/in-java-how-do-a-read-convert-an-inputstream-in-to-a-string

Comment: I wish I could do that @skaffman, however I must read the request body twice. Once to get a json object and the next one to get the string and I always get stream is already closed. Any thoughts?

Comment: tsunade21, your comment doesn't make sense.  The answer above tells you how to turn your input stream into a string.  Needing to read the same stream twice is very likely a bug.  Just use the resulting string in both places.

Comment: @James Moore, i think i didn't explain myself well before. I had to read the same stream twice because I was using jackson mapping that was reading the stream automatically without giving me any control whatsoever. I finally fixed it, using gson instead of jackson mapping.

Comment: @JamesMoore is right, reading the stream twice is a bug. You read a **Stream** from a source you cannot control, from your user's browser. There's simply no way to tell that client "hey, would you send your data once again, please?"

Answer (score 19):

Using [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io):

```
String requestStr = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 2):

Other way, using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```
ByteSource.wrap(ByteStreams.toByteArray(request.getInputStream()))
    .asCharSource(Charsets.UTF_8).read()
```

**See also:**

- http://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-inputstream-to-reader